# Age issue in How Old Are You

Tags: plot-explanation, how-old-are-you

In the Malayalam movie 'How old are you?' Manju Warrier's character is a 35 years old house wife. In an important sequence, it is being said that her driving license got expired and she was not aware of that. In Kerala, AFAIK, driving licenses are not issued to minors below 18 years (which I believe will be similar in other Indian states, too). And the issued license will be valid for 20 years from the date of issue. So she should have got her license at 15 years of age for it to expire at 35.

Is this a mistake that they missed to correct, or are there any exceptions to normal motor vehicle rule that I did not notice?

**Update**:

In the movie, license is used to appear in a car hit-and-run case. So it cannot be a light motor bike license, which one can get at the completion of 16 years of age.

**Update #2**:

[The rules for license according to Kerala MVD official site.](http://www.keralamvd.gov.in/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=53&Itemid=89)

Comment: Sorry, the validity should be read 20 years. i have updated the question

Comment: @noone: This question has a lot of assumptions which don't appear to be correct. A quick google search shows you can drive a motorcycle at 15. On top of that, I found a few pages suggesting license renewal is needed every five years. Finally, many people change/renew licenses after moving house/changing name due to marriage, etc. I think this question is too broad and unclear for these reasons.

Comment: @AndrewMartin - A motorcycle with an engine under 55cc the age is 16. For a motor vehicle, the age is 18. Expiration is 20 years for a "light motor" vehicle, or age 50 whichever comes first. http://www.delhi.gov.in/wps/wcm/connect/doit_transport/Transport/Home/Driving+Licence/Renewal+of+Driving+Licence http://india.angloinfo.com/transport/driving-licences/permanent-licence/

Comment: @JohnP: Maybe I was just looking at licenses for immigrants then. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

In the film, this incident is important and had shown as one of the mains reasons for husband of protagonist to hate her like she don't give focus to the family goal of migration. And it lead him and his daughter to travel abroad without taking by leaving her alone in India.

Also the four wheeler driving licene is valid for 20 years for the first time.

So, it explain this is a movie script mistake which never exposed at the release time and gone un-noticed.

Comment: This has been brought to my attention as 'low-quality because of its length and content.' Answers should not be based on subjective opinions ('I feel..') and should be drawn from the content of the film or from objective fact. I hope that you take this remark in the best possible spirit - we take no pleasure in criticising the work of other members and make such interventions in order to help you raise the standard of any content you post, which I hope you are not dissuaded from continuing to provide.Let's see if we can get this removed to help keep your rep. score from being unfairly lowered.

Comment: @StephenFrancis I elaborated with my points now

Comment: I cannot make any further comments on the quality of your edited answer as I am unfamiliar with the piece and its context, but I appreciate you taking my comments on board and giving it another go. Hope to see more posts from you soon.